# Indefinite article with uncountable nouns

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, uncountable-nouns

I'm writing something and I'm not sure which one is correct:

1. *to have **a** control over*
2. *to have control over*

I googled and found many examples written by native speakers who in fact used the article with *control*, as shown below:

- > the object... was to have a control over that person ([Reports of Cases Argued and Determined in the Court of King's Bench, Volume 5](https://books.google.hr/books?id=ymMDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA1055&dq=%22+to+have+a+control+over+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_x_by4JHPAhVhb5oKHXi0CzsQ6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=%22%20to%20have%20a%20control%20over%20%22&f=false)) (1834)
- > the people ought to have a control over their own affairs ([The London and Westminster Review, Volume 25; Volume 27](https://books.google.hr/books?id=vREbAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA71&dq=%22the+people+ought+to+have+a+control+over+their+own+affairs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0o6_Q4ZHPAhVtSZoKHRMDDioQ6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=%22the%20people%20ought%20to%20have%20a%20control%20over%20their%20own%20affairs%22&f=false)) (1836)
- > the Constitution... is to have a control over such institutions ([Social Theories of Jacksonian Democracy: Representative Writings of the Period 1825-1850](https://books.google.hr/books?id=4I32xdB-djsC&pg=PA179&dq=%22is+to+have+a+control+over+such+institutions%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifvPeV4pHPAhVlSZoKHfpxCi8Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20to%20have%20a%20control%20over%20such%20institutions%22&f=false)) (2003)

Comment: The examples you found should be ignored. Your first instinct was correct.

Comment: I know that "control" is an uncountable noun and shouldn't be used with an article; I am just interested to find out if there are ever instances when an uncountable noun like "control" can be used with an article, considering the examples I found by native speakers.

Comment: I suggest you put that in the question.  Please note, any "examples written by native speakers", should appear with links so we can see the examples in context.

Comment: I did, it was edited out. :)
I will put links, no problem.

Comment: "the object... was to have a control over that person" (http://tinyurl.com/h3c9fsn)
"the people ought to have a control over their own affairs"(http://tinyurl.com/gvarmp8)
"the Constitution... is to have a control over such institutions" (http://tinyurl.com/h8rt4yl)

While I was searching for the links, I found more examples; I can add those too if necessary.

Comment: @SJay Please avoid using URL shorteners on Stack Exchange sites. You can instead use `[site name](link)`, for example, use `[Google](https://google.com)` to add a link to [Google](https://google.com)

Comment: OK, I am a newbie here as you might have already guessed. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @SJay - 1834?!  Are you trying to understand English as used back then, or contemporary English?

Comment: These examples are unexceptional. Non-count nouns can act as count nouns in various circumstances, and take articles or other determiners: *a love that had no equal*, *my strange history and our stranger future*, *an ochre sand to replace the gray concrete*. See e.g. *[When can uncountable nouns be countable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/312018)* and older duplicates like *[The article “a/an” with uncountable nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/43757)* or *[Usage of an article in front of the structure “adjective + non countable noun.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/244772)*.

Comment: @SJay I added 1837 because that's when the **material quoted** was written, not when the book was written.

Comment: aparente001 I found more contemporary examples too... choster, thank you; I will check out those older posts; Andrew, ok, I thought it was a mistake

Comment: More contemporary examples: [The Psychology of Freedom] (https://books.google.hr/books?id=02ND1qHhN1EC&pg=PA16&dq=%22+have+a+control+over+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLgb-F6pHPAhVECpoKHYPgCjQQ6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=%22%20have%20a%20control%20over%20%22&f=false) (1996)

Comment: And these ones: [Reason Without Freedom](https://books.google.hr/books?id=S7iBAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22+have+a+control+over+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLgb-F6pHPAhVECpoKHYPgCjQQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22%20have%20a%20control%20over%20%22&f=false) (2000) and

[Human Resource Management](https://books.google.hr/books?id=ICnLzdl8mS8C&pg=PA640&dq=%22+have+a+control+over+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdrp3J7JHPAhXCHJoKHRz-DDE4ChDoAQgeMAE#v=onepage&q=%22%20have%20a%20control%20over%20%22&f=false) (2005)

Comment: The third example is from a book published in India, and I am not sure what to think about that in terms of native speakers (although I do believe that they are considered to be native speakers, just of a different English variety), so here is a different example just in case somebody might object: [Success in Small Business Is a Laughing Matter](https://books.google.hr/books?id=AsYMQ6fe88wC&pg=PR10&dq=%22+to+have+a+control+over+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU_Jyd7ZHPAhUBKpoKHaq7Ays4ChDoAQgvMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%20to%20have%20a%20control%20over%20%22&f=false) (2007)

Comment: Indefinite articles may be used with certain non-count noun usages in some  circumstances (quite apart from countification having taken place, eg "I'll have a coffee / three coffees, please"). In 'He spoke with a great enthusiasm' the indefinite article is optional, though 'enthusiasm' cannot be considered a count usage here (*'He spoke with two / several / many [great] enthusiasms'). // This is another such example where 'a' is optional.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, choster wrote:

> These examples are unexceptional. Non-count nouns can act as count nouns in various circumstances, and take articles or other determiners: *a love that had no equal*, *my strange history and our stranger future*, *an ochre sand to replace the gray concrete*. See e.g. *[When can uncountable nouns be countable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/312018)* and older duplicates like *[The article “a/an” with uncountable nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/43757)* or *[Usage of an article in front of the structure “adjective + non countable noun.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/244772)*.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> Indefinite articles may be used with certain non-count noun usages in some  circumstances (quite apart from countification having taken place, eg "I'll have a coffee / three coffees, please"). In 'He spoke with a great enthusiasm' the indefinite article is optional, though 'enthusiasm' cannot be considered a count usage here (*'He spoke with two / several / many [great] enthusiasms'). // This is another such example where 'a' is optional.